# 2-factor authentication key formats for Kraken and Bitstamp

Tags: bitstamp, kraken

Does anyone know how to format the string that you type into the Google Authenticator app in order to generate 2FA codes for Kraken? For context, the following URL is highly relevant:—

https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format

I accidentally deleted everything from my 'phone, so I had to re-install the Google Authenticator app. Unfortunately, my backup file just contains the secret component of each key, and I don't know the format for the rest of the string. For Poloniex, it's enough just to enter the secret while setting up the app, but other exchanges reject this minimalism. Presumably, they want something in the style of

otpauth://totp/BobsExchange:alice@example.com?secret=ABCDEFGHIJKLMN12&issuer=BobsExchange

…where I know that I'm Alice, that Bob owns the exchange and that my secret is ABCDEFGHIJKLMN12. What I don't know is the exact format.

Bonus marks if anyone can answer this question for Bitstamp as well as Kraken. Official support is likely to be overwhelmed during the present cryptocurrency boom.

EDIT: If you've got 2FA set up on your Android 'phone, it means that you have an sqlite database file on it somewhere, with the answer to my question. [This page](http://eduncan911.com/technology/hardware/google-authenticator-databases-move-copy-fix.html) suggests that it's at /data/data/com.google.android.apps.authenticator2/databases/.

Answer (score 1):

```
otpauth://totp/TOTPID?secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&period=30
otpauth://totp/username@Bitstamp?secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Where for Kraken TOTPID tells what the TOTP secret is for. Example: "Kraken%20CZNY%20trade"